# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (in eval)

Tags: python

I don't know what is the problem with the code:

```
def equal():
    entry.delete(0, len(entry.get()))
    entry.insert(index='end', string=eval(entry.get()))
```

but I got this error and I don't know what is the problem:

```
    entry.insert(index='end', string=eval(entry.get()))
  File "<string>", line 0

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

If anyone knows what I did wrong, let me know.

Comment: So, does your code delete the existing text from `entry` first, then expect to use `eval()` on the, presumably, now empty text string?

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't notice it, thank you
 ,
So how can I delete the text in the `entry` and place another text in its place?

Comment: Well, that is what your code is doing now if it weren’t for the error.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for helping me